# Extract filename and id from its name

Tags: regex

I have a file with text

```
# co2a0000123.rd
# co2c0000124.rd
```

I need to use regex and extract `co2a0000123` in group 1 and `a` or `c` as highlighted in group 2 of regex expression

I have tried

```
(\B[a|c])([a-z0-9]+).(?:[a-z]+)
```

What happens is `([a-z0-9]+).(?:[a-z]+)` this part of regex gives `co2a0000123` in group 1 as desired but as soon as I add `(\B[a|c])` in the beginning or end `co2a0000123` changes to `co2a` in group 1 and gives 'a' in Group 2.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes (\B[a|c])([a-z0-9]+).(?:[a-z]+) and a few variations.
But then the second group clips the results of first group

Comment: See [`(?m)^# +(\S{3}(\S)\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/LSVFgD/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try for example [`\s(\w+?([ac])\w*)\.`](https://regexr.com/4d4cq)

Group 1 will be the part between a space and a dot.
Group 2 will be the first `a` or `c` anywhere except the first letter within Group 1.